# Modifying the URL allows some users to see content they shouldn't

Tags: javascript, c#

My company has a website that is used by internal and external users.  Certain information is not able to be seen by external users.  However, if they add something to the URL (ie. ?ParentRsvId=4794094), they are able to pull up that reservation and view it.  How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: Well sounds like you need to learn about user sessions and permissions.

Comment: Or bearer token auth, or any number of other good solutions. This is way too broad.

Comment: Are you web-developer or you only use you company website?

Comment: I'm a developer, very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you have **no** control over the client in a WebApplication. You can tell it that something should be done, but you can never asume it is actually done. So JavaScript will not help you 1 Iota her.

About your only way to block areas and ensure sensible requests, is via [Programm flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-flow_diagram) on the server side:

In your case, the Reservation View should check if the Logged in User account is supposed to be there. And if it is not, you simply send a redirect to the login page/error message. The client can either follow the redirect. Or stay on the redirect page. In both cases, no information is leaked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have authorization checks on the server-side code that generates the page content.  When rendering the page, check that the user has access to view the content and if not show a 401 error or redirect to a page that they have the authorization to see.